Collaborative calendar with RTL support and reminder message sending
I'm in a group of people who currently share information about activities using an instant messaging group. For various reasons, we would like to have a more structured mechanism - a proper calendar, which can be viewed as such.
Requirements:

Supports the use of Right-to-Left languages, like Arabic and Hebrew, in message bodies, titles and meta-data - with appropriate direction and alignment of content and no ugly gaffes.
Not on a platform where content/communications are likely to be data mined, copied to the NSA etc. So not Google, Microsoft, Yahoo and the like.
Access must be restricted via login-with-credentials.
Different permission levels: For reading, for adding events, for managing the group/system.
Supports remote access using some common protocol (maybe credentials-protected ICS? I'm not familiar with how calendar sharing typically works).

And finally, a desired feature:

Users can choose to have reminder messages sent to them at given times before an event (e.g. 1 day before, 1 hour before) - vis SMS, Telegram, WhatsApp, whatever the calendar platform supports. If it supports multiple options among those than great.

Does such a platform exist?
Notes:

It doesn't have to be gratis.
The management interface doesn't have to be multi-lingual
We'd rather not self-host, but if no other alternative is found we might consider it.


One (nonperfect) possible solution is to use Zimbra.
It support right to left text input (page 19), support users login, can be set to different levels of access (read, read/write, admin), it is platform you should manage (not Google, Yahoo, etc.), support web client (not sure about other protocols to access calendar).
Unfortunately all above is about user sharing own calendar, not sure if they support dedicated shared calendar.

Could I note create an artificial user whose password is shared, so that for creating events, everyone logs in as that user?

@einpoklum, no, one user create the calendar, other users are created (in the system). And owner share his calendar with others. And give them (per user or per group) rights (to read, to write/create or to administer/delete) This can help you to provide more granular access.
